# Docker inspect showing memory and nanocpus as 0

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-run

I have deployed a container using the `docker stack deploy` command.

The service gets deployed properly and also the contianer is running.

I have specified some resource reservation constaints as follows:

```
      deploy:
        mode: replicated
        replicas: 1
        resources:
          reservations:
            cpus: '0.25'
            memory: 512M
        restart_policy:
          condition: on-failure
          max_attempts: 3
```

But when I try to check the allocated memory and cpu resources, the `docker inspect container_name` command shows 0 as their values

```
"Memory": 0,
"NanoCpus": 0,
```

Answer (score -2):

I had also same issue using docker-compose to make up images via yaml fie. Issue was due to the docker-compose version. It worked in docker-compose version 1.29.0.

root@xprdpgntrsap02 bin]# docker inspect container_test01 |grep -i cpu

```
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "NanoCpus": 500000000,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
```

hope it will be
useful for someone

Comment: Wasn't the question about `docker stack deploy`?